# Why does my automated Blue Prism process fail in some stages in scheduler-mode, when these steps work totally fine in debug-mode?

Tags: process, automation, blueprism, rpa

For example I implemented a stage "Activate Application" that works in debug mode perfectly, but fails when I use schedule-mode or when I simply drag and drop the process on a runtime resource.

A second example that fails: I implemented an action called "Navigate to URL". These action sets the URL from the input variable In_URL firstly in the URL bar in browser Google Chrome. Then the URL bar is focused and the enter button is hit in the last stage.

In schedule mode the following error appeared:

> ERROR: Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Navigate Stage 'Click URL Field' on page 'Navigate to URL' - Could not identify process owning the current foreground window

Actually there is only one Google Chrome window, so I don't understand why it says these error message.

[image: Please regard an image of the action]

Comment: Have you observed the remote Runtime Resource? It's impossible to tell exactly what is occurring from just your post - this could stem from anything environment-related that differs between your test resources.

Answer (score 0):

These issues are typically due to either Windows being locked, or using RDP to connect to the resources (RDP does not work well with Blue Prism). In both cases, the desktop will not be active, so any active accessibility or region elements will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Meanwhile I solved the problem. I did not use Login Agent. After Login on the resource machine, these steps like "Activate Application" or "Navigate to URL" work finely. 

But now there is another problem: I needed to identify some elements via region mode. Blueprism does not recognize these elements in scheduler mode. In Debug mode, and via start from the control room it worked perfectly. 
Please help.

Comment: Something has to be changing when it's running via scheduled mode. Is Login Agent unlocking the desktop before the schedule runs? Also, you could set up the process to save a screenshot when it hits an exception. I do that myself on most surface-level automations, since it helps to see what went wrong.

Comment: There are many reasons why this could happen: Your bot is locking: SA does not work well with a locked bot.. if at all. If you have logged in manually and then use the agent to login, you now possibly have 2 sessions logged into the same bot and you bot login does not have control of the bot. your resolution on the bot is different then what it was when you created process using SA. These are just a few (or maybe they are all factors in your case). You will have to eliminate each to identify the issue